# Access Standalone PHP File With Wordpress Installed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just installed wordpress on a site. However, I have some standalone php files that I use for analyzing database data on the site that now return a 404 when trying to access them.

For example:

```
www.mywordpresssite.com/myscripts/myscript.php
```

This returns a 404.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any way I can achieve normal access to the said directory/file but without upsetting the current functionality of Wordpress?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .htaccess file to this

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myscripts/(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does allow me access but it seems to break the pages - home page is ok, but www.mywordpresssite.com/page no longer works and returns a server error page

Comment: Actually I just put the original code above the new code and it now works so thanks

Comment: That should work. Did you change anything else? WP is in the web root right?

Comment: Ok I updated my answer for you as you have done it. It should have worked the other way too, but if it works then good. Up vote or accept if I was able to help you? thanks.

Comment: I do not know why it broke it - WP is in the root but does have custom permalink if that could be it? I need to add a second folder but I can still only access the first?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could be the permalink. You should be able to add another line or as many as you want. Just put another line under the line with myscripts like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/otherfolder/(.*)$ [OR]`

Comment: nope that does not work, still the first link works, but not the second? do not know what is going on!

Comment: Permalinks is probably wreaking havoc. As a test you can disable permalinks and see if everything is working including the other folders.

Comment: It is really weird as now neither of the two directories allow me in, even though one was 2 minutes ago. I will keep testing - thanks for your help!

Comment: If all else fails, You could just add a .htaccess in the myscripts directory and the other one and put this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>` inside the .htaccess that's in your myscritps and other directory since it's being a pain. WP assumes you're not doing anything else but working with WP. annoying.

Comment: It is taking over my site - even that idea does not solve it.

Comment: refresh permalinks and see what happens. Disable/enable.

Comment: No change! Cannot access either page!

Comment: The issue was because the directory was password protected and Wordpress treated the 401 as a 404. Therefore adding ErrorDocument 401 Default into .htaccess solved it

Comment: Ah.. didn't know it was password protected. That would do it. Glad you found the that issue.