# Run a PHP script in Wordpress when a certain URL format is called?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to execute a PHP script when example.com/12345 is entered as the URL. Is there a specific file where I should place this script, or somewhere in wp-admin where I can set this up?

Comment: What about adding a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` ? Then you can call what ever file you want on what ever URL you want ...

Comment: Are you saying you want a command line (CLI) script to run, triggered by a Wordpress page? Or do you just want to put a pretty name on a PHP file? What does this PHP file contain?

Comment: @LeonardChallis pretty name on a PHP file. One idea I have is that it will check $_SERVER for the URL, and execute a small PHP script if the URL matches the criteria.

Comment: When you say "PHP file" do you mean a web page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress
See this post

Comment: @LeonardChallis No, I mean I have a snippet of PHP code, and I need to drop it somewhere so Wordpress will pick it up before a 404 page is served.

Comment: Is this specifically for 404 pages?

Comment: @Ashkar it looks like that explains how to add a custom template to a particular page. I need to run a PHP script before a 404 page is served, due to a URL being entered that Wordpress doesn't recognize.

Comment: @LeonardChallis not really, but it's for URLs that don't match up with pages that have been added in the admin. So, for all intents and purposes..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249278/access-standalone-php-file-with-wordpress-installed So you are looking for this .

Comment: @Ashkar I figured it out, see my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's as simple as adding a function into functions.php that fires on init:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    if(preg_match('~[0-9]~', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )){
        //script goes here
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action) in your [functions file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) to do something when a page is not found:

```
function page_not_found()
{
    if (is_404()) {
        /* put your custom code here */
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'page_not_found');
```

Of course, if you want to adjust the condition of when your custom code runs, you can use [other functions such as these](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404#Related).